# Flutter show a widget while an async await task is being executed

Tags: flutter

I have the following onTap event which executes a function:

```
onTap: () async {
  await firestoreUserData.updateProfilePicture(url);
})
```

Is it possible to show some kind of loading indicator (a widget, like a ProgressIndicator) while the await is being executed? I cannot use a futurebuilder, as this is an onTap event.

Comment: when entering the tap, you can update a variable that controls the appearance or not of the activity indicator, however, for it to appear, you need to update the widget (scaffold in case it is on the full screen) either through a setstate or of a stream or futurebuild. to remove the activity indicator, use a .them () instead of the await and update the status of the control variable and again update the widget where it will appear.

Comment: thanks i implemented it by making a global bool and setting the state to change the bool, if the bool is true it will show a loading indicator when it rebuilds the tree, when the await is finished it sets the state again setting the bool to false

Comment: *"Is it possible to show some kind of loading indicator (a widget, like a ProgressIndicator) while the await is being executed? I cannot use a futurebuilder, as this is an onTap event."* - yes you can use `FutureBuilder`, it does not matter if it is `onTap` event or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the loading state (define it in the class).

```
onTap: () async {
  setState(() { _isLoading = true });//show loader
  await firestoreUserData.updateProfilePicture(url);//wait for update
  setState(() { _isLoading = false });//hide loader
})
```

In your build:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_isLoading)
         return Text("Loading");
    else
         //your stuff here.
}
```